# Array of JLabel object initializing issue

Tags: java, arrays, initialization

So, I initialized it as an array object, and when I go to initialize the individual objects,it won't give them a value

```
/* 
-A java program GUI for Food to allow user to type the food 
*/
public class Catagorygui extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

//attributes
JPanel panel;   
JButton button; 
JFrame frame;   
JLabel item;    
JTextField item1;   
JLabel cost;    
JTextField cost1;   
JLabel percentused; 
JLabel name;    
JTextField name1;   
JLabel paidupfront; 
JTextField paidupfront1;

public Appartment2 g=new Appartment2();

private static String rec=" ";

private JTextField [] upfront=new JTextField[g.getPeople().size()];//must initialize
private JTextField [] percent=new JTextField[g.getPeople().size()];
private JLabel [] usernames=new JLabel[g.getPeople().size()];//for loop that gives them values
private int a;

public Catagorygui (){
    g.addPerson("Ali");
    g.addPerson("Kacie");

    for(int i=0;i<a;i++)
    {

        usernames[i]=new JLabel("poop");//somehow not initializing it
        percent [i]=new JTextField(10);
        upfront [i]=new JTextField(10);
        percent[i].addActionListener(this);
    }
    System.out.println(g.getpeople().get(0).getName());//ali
    System.out.print(usernames[0]);//SAYS INDEX OUT OF BOUNDS, should say'poop'
    //
    a=g.getpeople().size();
```

Comment: If ```usernames[0]``` throws index out of bounds, that means the array size is ```0```.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i=0; i<a; i++)
```

Yes, keep iterating while `i < a`, but what's `a`? Where did you initialize it? Any `int` primitive type has a default value of `0` in Java. so `0 < 0` is always false and no iterations are done.

Answer (score 0):

`a=g.getpeople().size();` should be before the `for` loop

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12040141)

Comment: @GauravDave It is not request for clarification or criticism. It is explanation why the code doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, just a move a little some variables...

the  for loop is not executed because **a** is not initialized (or it is, but at the end of the constructor...) just move the assign of the variable a before you go in the for loop and not the error must be gone!
**a=g.getpeople().size();**

## Example:

```
public Catagorygui (){
    g.addPerson("Ali");
    g.addPerson("Kacie");
    a = g.getpeople().size();   // move up to here
    for(int i=0;i<a;i++)
    {
        usernames[i]=new JLabel("poop");//somehow not initializing it
        percent [i]=new JTextField(10);
        upfront [i]=new JTextField(10);
        percent[i].addActionListener(this);
    }
    System.out.println(g.getpeople().get(0).getName());//ali
    System.out.print(usernames[0]);//SAYS INDEX OUT OF BOUNDS, should say'poop'
        //
```